# How to express block diagonal matrices in mathematical notation?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, notation, block-matrices

Suppose I have a block diagonal matrix that looks like this

$$C = \begin{bmatrix} A & 0\\ 0 & B\end{bmatrix}$$

then I would write $C = \mbox{diag} (A, B)$, however, what if I have a block diagonal matrix that is mirrored, i.e.

$$D = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & A\\ B & 0\end{bmatrix}$$

How can I express $D$ in mathematical notation?

Comment: There is no commonly accepted notation, not even for a simple antidiagonal matrix. (Strictly speaking, your matrix is not block diagonal, but "block antidiagonal".)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may write $D=\operatorname{antidiag}(A,B)$ but this is by no means a standard notation.